# How to prevent pyspark to read parquet file header record as just another row instead of reading it as header?

Tags: pyspark, parquet, databricks-community-edition

I have a parquet file with 11 columns. I tried executing below ways in pyspark to read the file. It still assigns header names like Prop_0, Prop_1, Prop_2 instead of reading the starting header as header row.

1.

```
spark.read.parquet("/FileStore/tables/Order.parquet").show()
```

```
dfpq_new=spark.read.format("parquet").load("/FileStore/tables/Order-1.parquet")
```

2. 

```
dfpq_new=spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).load("/FileStore/tables/Order-1.parquet")
```

[image: headers prop_0 prop_1 instead of header names from parquet file]

However, when I create an dataframe and save it as parquet file, and then read it -

```
data1 = (("Bob", "IT", 4500), \
("Maria", "IT", 4600),  \
("James", "IT", 3850),   \
("Maria", "HR", 4500),  \
("James", "IT", 4500),    \
("Sam", "HR", 3300),  \
("Jen", "HR", 3900),    \
("Jeff", "Marketing", 4500), \
("Anand", "Marketing", 2000),\
("Shaid", "IT", 3850) \
)
col = ["Name", "MBA_Stream", "SEM_MARKS"]
marks_pq_df = spark.createDataFrame(data1, col)
marks_pq_df.write.parquet("/FileStore/table/markspq.parquet", mode='overwrite')

spark.read.format("parquet").load("/FileStore/table/markspq.parquet").show()
```

[image: reads_headers_from_parquet_file]

I am using databricks community edition.

Comment: There is most likely an issue in how the first file was created. However without a reproducible example we cannot help much further.

Comment: As @ScootCork probably an error on the file. To give you a second idea, maybe open it giving the `.schema(schema)`.

Comment: You meant this ? @Memristor Did not work.                                                            
from pyspark.sql.types import *
orderSchema = StructType([StructField("Region", StringType() ,True)
,StructField("Country", StringType() ,True)
,StructField("ItemType", StringType() ,True)
,StructField("SalesChannel", StringType() ,True)
...
])
df=spark.read.parquet("/FileStore/tables/Order-1.parquet",schema=orderSchema)